# AChartEngine set panning in line chart android

Tags: android, charts

I implemented a graph demo using AChartEngine library. And set margin color transparent using this:

```
mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01));
```

My problem is that when I pan or zoom the renderer than it overlaping y-axis. I set margin color and background transparent to display background image.

Without pan

http://i42.tinypic.com/w133i1.png

With pan

http://i44.tinypic.com/sghkxw.png

Answer (score 0):

Finally I am giving answer of my own question. I digged in AChartEngine library and modified some code. I update the drawPath method from AbstractChart.java